# Why does my command fail even if I use `|| echo ""`

Tags: bash

I run my bash script with -e

```
set -e
git push --delete sometag || echo "git delete tag failed"
echo "some other commands"
```

However git push returns a fatal error, and the rest of the script is not executed (it does execute `echo "git delete tag failed"`)

I thought that was the purpose of using `||`. Is a "fatal" error any different?

Note: I have seen other questions but they say that || is the solution

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. This is what I did: 1. `mkdir testdir`, 2. `cd testdir`, 3. `git init`, 4. Write these three lines to a file `testscript`, 5. ran `bash testscript`. It says `fatal: --delete doesn't make sense without any refs`, `git delete tag failed`, `some other commands`, as expected. Please include steps to reproduce

Comment: @thatotherguy I assume "these three lines" refers to the OP's three lines. :-) Wouldn't `set -o pipefail` cause this behavior? Reading its description suggests it should, but I still can't reproduce.

Comment: @ooga There's no piping in this script so `pipefail` would have no effect

Comment: Apparently I confused `||` and `|` (and just generally wasn't thinking)! So the problem is that the "command list" is true so there's no overall failure. To get the behavior he wants he should do something like `if ! git push --delete sometag; then echo "git delete tag failed"; exit; fi; echo "some other commands";`

Comment: [Never use `set -e`.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)